# Why is Hive storing records in table "a.loginE-4"?

Tags: hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

I've a hive table `a.login`. When I use Hcatalog to store data into that table, I receive notice:

> Successfully stored 36579 records (2643326 bytes) in: "a.login"

But data were stored into table `a.loginE-4`. Please tell me what is that table? and why to fix it ?

Comment: Can u see definition of both the table ..  May both are referring same location ...

Comment: No, I'm just create one table ..